# Ruby: Is it possible to redefine a method but leave subclasses unchanged?

Tags: ruby

Suppose you have the following Ruby classes:

```
class A
  def self.greet
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

class B < A; end;
class C < B; end;
```

Is it possible to redefine `greet` on `B` in such a way that `C` still uses the original definition without modifying `C`?

(I understand that "you're doing it wrong" is a probable reaction, but please assume for a moment that there's a good reason for doing this.)

### Update

It's good to see yet another demonstration that Ruby will let you do whatever you want. However, to anyone finding this question and thinking of doing likewise, I should say that **I did eventually realize I was doing it wrong**; C needed to subclass A directly.

Read on to receive your shotgun, and watch where you're aiming it. :)

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to do this *without* using #super on `C`.

Comment: @Agis - the idea is that the weird behavior `B` needs is `B`'s problem, and I don't want `C` to have to know or care about it.

Comment: Then why C inherits from B? Maybe you need to re-think your inheritance model.

Comment: @Agis - because it needs `B`'s other behaviors. :)

Comment: You could abstract this common behavior then. Whatever :)

Comment: @Agis - You will be pleased to read my update. Do try to contain your gloating, though. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def B.greet
  puts self == B ? 'beeeee' : super
end
```

This means that B is aware that you want to change its version of `greet` but only for `B` and no other decedent classes.

Answer (score 2):

When the class is "B", do your thing, otherwise call super:

```
class B
  def self.greet
    if self == B
      puts "my new self"
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

If inheritance keeps pushing you to add tricky things like this, you might way to play with modules. Here's a fun read [on Ruby inheritance vs. modules](http://ducktypo.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-inheritance-sucks.html)

Comment: Actually, I really like @adam's clean syntax, except with `self == B`...no need to call on the ancestors ;-)

Comment: You are right that modules would be the normal way of handling this kind of inheritance.